# python selenium set a limit time to page loading and continue next step in force

Tags: python, selenium, driver

I've written a selenium program to search specific keywords using google.
But I found that it always waits for the page to load, sometimes it waits too long, and the page seems to be stuck there. Then my program stopped there with a timeout exception.
as my code shows below:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(input, keyword).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

I need when the google page gets the keyword into the input area, maybe 1 or 2 seconds later, the program will go on to the next step the get another keyword from the main window.
I've tried the implicit or explicit wait, but I don't want to deal with the exception, I don't want the exception to interrupt my program, I don't mind if several pages have been completely executed.

How to set it up?

Comment: my problem is I need to set a restrict time, for example, 10 sec, if the page is running smoothly, the program will jump to next step automatically maybe in just 1 or 2 sec, but when the page is stuck, the time is uncertain, maybe 20sec, maybe 30, or even timed out, and program is over.